# VBA - How to change colour of no. of columns based on value in cell?

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

Can anyone please help as I'm new to Excel VBA?

My requirement is to change colour of a range of cell based on value in a particular cell.

e.g. if I've cell B8 with value 2 then change the background colour of B9:B11 to red and C9:C11 to red.

and say if the cell B8 has value 3 then change the background colour of B9:B11 to red, C9:C11 to red and then D9:D11 red.

The range expands to B9:E11 for value 4 and so on. So need a VBA code, Conditional formating for 100 value will not be time effective I guess.

How do I do this?

Thanks 
Amrik

Comment: use [conditional formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional formatting.  Select B9:B11, make a conditional formatting rule based upon formula (=$B$8 >= COLUMN(B$9).  Copy B9:B11 to C9:C11, etc and the conditional formatting rule will follow.

If you prefer to be more explicit, you could further avoid vba and just use propel (http://propel.codeplex.com).  This [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84208129/pf.png) does what I think you described.  Just hide rows 1 and 2 when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a worksheet event handler to catch when the value in the cell changes. And using the code below you'll be able to change the color of the range

```
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(11, Cells(2, 8))).Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, what I don't know is what user is going to enter in the cell. I need to loop in for what ever the number the user is going to enter and then change the colour for that many columns. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: Did you test the code you posted ?. And should the code depend in any way on what is the value(s) within changed range? Also in such Sub it should be checked if changed range is within range of our interest and Exit SUb if not, otherwise the code would run every time sheet is changed.

Comment: I get runtime error '1004' everytime I change something in the worksheet.

Comment: Yes avb, you are right. The code is run everytime sheet is changed.

Comment: This was an example of how it could be done, you can add a command button, or call the line in another function, ... worksheet_Change event handler wasn't the main focus of the answer